# How to change the color of odd and even rows of a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

When creating a list you get the option to make the odd rows blank and the even rows grey.

[image]

It generates a JSON-code (I think). How can I change the color from the even rows from grey to blue.

This is the JSON code it generates:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "%",
            "operands": [
              "@rowIndex",
              2
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      "sp-css-backgroundColor-neutralBackground",
      {
        "operator": ":",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "%",
                "operands": [
                  "@rowIndex",
                  2
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill",
          ""
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the rows with white background or the rows with gray background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple classes in `additionalRowClass` property in above JSON as per your requirement.

For example, to change the color of rows with gray background to blue, you need to add `ms-fontColor-blue` class to the first condition, like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "%",
            "operands": [
              "@rowIndex",
              2
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      "sp-css-backgroundColor-neutralBackground ms-fontColor-blue",
      {
        "operator": ":",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "%",
                "operands": [
                  "@rowIndex",
                  2
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill",
          ""
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can find more predefined classed you can use in JSON formatting at:

1. [Predefined classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#predefined-classes)
2. [Reusable SharePoint Online Classes for Modern UI](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/)

**Note**: In SharePoint JSON formatting, `@rowIndex` starts with 0.